# How do I Make a custom post type get a custom post template in a plugin

Tags: custom-post-types, plugin-development, page-template

I am writing a plugin in which I am adding a custom post type(called 'events') using register_post_type. Additionally I want it to use single-event.php instead of the regular single.php.
The current structure of the plugin folder is :

- plugin-main-file.php
- single-event.php

I know its possible if I place it inside my theme directory, but I want it to be placed inside the plugin and utilize it. 
How do I do it? Any custom function for that?

Comment: Possible duplicate on stackoverflow: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4647604/wp-use-file-in-plugin-directory-as-custom-page-template

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function get_custom_post_type_template($single_template) {
     global $post;

     if ($post->post_type == 'events') {
          $single_template = dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/single-event.php';
     }
     return $single_template;
}
add_filter( 'single_template', 'get_custom_post_type_template' );
```

[Source](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/single_template)

Or you could use:

```
add_filter( 'template_include', 'single_event_template', 99 );

function single_event_template( $template ) {

    if ( is_singular('event') ) {
        $new_template = locate_template( array( 'single-event.php' ) );
        if ( '' != $new_template ) {
            return $new_template ;
        }
    }

    return $template;
}
```

[Source](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/template_include)

Or you could use [`locate_template`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/locate_template)

Comment: Using `locate_template` the file will be searched in theme folder, where OP says it should be in plugin folder. My +1 is for first approach.

Comment: locate_template is used in many quality plugins to display templates.

Comment: It is used in many quality plugins to display templates from **theme**. See [source](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/ef436cb6e06b065b5a49b48157a0509d56f1aefe/wp-includes/template.php#L462): that function **can't** be used to load files from something external to theme, e.g. in plugin folder.

Comment: Can if the template is included in the plugin. Look at Genesis WooCommerce Connect.

Comment: That plugins support theming. It means that firts files are searched in theme (using `locate_template`) if the file is not found in theme, then the files are loaded from plugin folder using [`load_template`](http://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/load_template/)

Comment: Nothing wrong with that.

Answer (score 1):

This is what I've always done. Not sure if you need both $wp_query and $post but it's always worked for me.

Just put this in `plugin-main-file.php`

```
/**
 * Add single template for events post type plugin
 */
function custom_template_events_post_type_plugin($single) {
      global $wp_query, $post;
      if ($post->post_type == "events"){
        $template = dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/single-event.php';
        if(file_exists( $template ))
            return $template;
      }
        return $single;
    }
    add_filter('single_template', 'custom_template_events_post_type_plugin');
```